# Importing IEnumerable in constructor

Tags: c#, .net, mef

Im looking through some code trying to learn MEF: I understand how to import for example services but ifound something that looks like its importing a collection in the constructor.

Where does the IObservableCollection get instantiated and populated? When importing custom classes its easy to follow but when importing a collection where are the items are populated from?

```
private readonly IObservableCollection<NetworkServiceType> _observableNetworkServiceTypes;

[ImportingConstructor]
public MyConstructor (IObservableCollection<NetworkServiceType> 
    observableNetworkServiceTypes)    
{
   _observableNetworkServiceTypes = observableNetworkServiceTypes;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the question has been edited but hopefully this answer still helps.

The first part of the question I believe you understand.  The `IObservableCollection<NetowrkServiceType>` should be instantiated by whoever instantiates this class; meaning they are also responsible for having this ready to pass to the constructor.  DI and other things that can / may be involved to help with this but all the same the DI is responsible in that case.

You understand how classes are instantiated and passed in but the items in the collection, where are they instantiated.  Well that can vary but since this is a collection there should already be an array of items in the collection.  However; since this is also by reference those items could change elsewhere; meaning they may be populated after instantiation or who knows... maybe even during enumeration of the list.  It's **not safe to assume they are already instantiated** to write safe code but **it's also logical to assume it should be**; in other words, you need to consider if you want to use the passed in reference or duplicate it in your constructor so that you have your own reference of the collection.

And hopefully to help with the original question before edited; which I see you still represent in the comment below.  I would guess that `IEnumerableCollection<NetworkServiceType>` does have a base of `IEnumerable<T>` as well as others but `IEnumerableCollection<T>` is a unique interface (not .NET that I'm aware of) so I can't say for certain.  (And just for the sake of saying so; making a type that's named `IEnumerableCollection` is redundant because a Collection should be Enumerable already...)  Anyways, back to the point.  You originally say, "when importing IEnumerable I can't find where the items are populated from."  I wanted to share this hoping that it helps...  When something is referred to or referenced as `Enumerable`, `IEnumerable`, or `IEnumerable<T>` then it's more like you're referencing a function or delegate that when called returns a value.  The function or method has a place holder that when called again by the same caller it can pick up where it left off; basically allowing you to return more than one item from the same function when called in iteration.  One way of doing this is with the `yield` keyword as you'll see in the example.  The return value can be an object already referenced or it may instantiated at the time of calling.  *There's more to `Enumerable` but for now let's leave it at that.*

This means that when you reference an `Enumerable` type the items you're expecting from the enumeration may or may not exist yet.  You're always simply referencing a method to get items (to make it easier to understand).  I use the term querying here, although it's more relevant when using Linq and SQL but the idea is the same.  We can have a reference to a query and never get any items until we call it.

Consider this small application for example that hopefully helps illustrate all the jibber jabber above.  This is a small console app that you can copy and paste.  Place a break point on line 10 (`foreach (var item in items)`) and one on line 18 (`yield return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();`.  Notice that we hit the line 10 break point before we do 18 even though we already have a reference to items on line 9.  As a matter of fact if we never use the `foreach` (or iterate the items in any way) in this application then we will never instantiate the new object at all (meaning `Activator.CreateInstance<T>();` never gets called.)  It's not until we iterate over items (query it as I call it) that we actually get the new objects.
Note:  This is not to say this is what you're instantiation in the question is doing as I assume it's not.  I am simply illustrating how `Enumerable` types are viewed by .NET.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Question_Answer_Console_App
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // A reference to IEnumerable<T>
            // Behaves much like a function when used in a loop.
            var items = GetItems<object>();

            // For each works on IEnumerable types and internally calls the GetEnumerator() method.
            // GetEnumerator() returns IEnumerator<T> which has 1 property and 2 methods :: Current, MoveNext(), and Reset()
            // It basically calls GetEnumerator() and then MoveNext() and Current to give us the results
            foreach (var item in items)
                Console.WriteLine(item);

            //Here's an example of the loop above written manually just to help you visualize it.
            var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                Console.WriteLine(enumerator.Current);

            //Finally; we can't write syntax but here's a method (seen below) that's much like the foreach syntax.
            ForEach(items, item => Console.WriteLine(item));

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void ForEach<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
        {
            IEnumerator<T> enumerator = items.GetEnumerator(); 
            iterateItems();

            void iterateItems()
            {
                // Notice that it's not actually until we get HERE calling MoveNext() that the yield return Activator.CreateInstance<T>() is actually called in our application.
                // And even now we don't have a reference to it ourselves; it's just placed into the Current property of the IEnumerator<T> type.
                var hasAnotherItem = enumerator.MoveNext();
                if (hasAnotherItem)
                {
                    // HERE is where we finally gain our own reference to the instantiated object for this example.
                    T currentItem = enumerator.Current;
                    action.Invoke(currentItem);
                    iterateItems();
                }
            }
        }

        static IEnumerable<T> GetItems<T>()
        {
            yield return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        }
    }
    // Outputs: 
    // System.Object
    // System.Object
    // System.Object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by searching for

```
[Export(typeof(IObservableCollection<NetworkServiceType>))]
```